# escape HTML chracters

Tags: javascript

I need to HTML encode chracters like my input is `<test>` my expected output is `&lt;test&gt;`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I tried to format your code but am not sure whether the result is a expected?!

Comment: Yeah, please clarify your question.

Comment: i want html enocode.. like < is equal to &lt and > is equal to &gt

Answer (score 2):

```
var encoded = htmlEncode('<test>');    // returns "&lt;test&gt;"

// ...

function htmlEncode(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var txt = document.createTextNode(str);
    div.appendChild(txt);
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Encoder.js](http://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js)

- **htmlDecode:** Decodes HTML encoded text
  to its original state.
- **htmlEncode:** Encodes HTML to either
  numerical or HTML entities. This is
  determined by the EncodeType
  property.

HTML encode text from an input element. This will prevent double encoding.

```
var encoded = Encoder.htmlEncode(document.getElementById('input'));
```

To encode but to allow double encoding which means any existing entities such as & will be converted to &amp;

```
var dblEncoded = Encoder.htmlEncode(document.getElementById('input'),true);
```

Comment: `escape` and `unescape` have nothing to do with HTML-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) to replicate special characters.

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars() and do your own str_replace() for the html comments

Comment: I, too, did not notice the `javascript` tag :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function simpleEscape(str) {
    return str.replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
}

var myStr = '<test>';
alert(simpleEscape(myStr));
```

Easiest I can think of (provided that this is all you intend to replace).